# JS: localCompare drives me nuts

Tags: javascript

don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my script stops at this funny `localCompare` line. Don't have clue, why :(

```
function enableTimeInput()
{
  var e = document.getElementById("sel_dateunit");
  var aDateUnit = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  var disable = aDateUnit.localCompare("weekly");
  ...
}
```

According to Firebug the value of `aDateUnit` is `"weekly"`. Btw. this is the value that I expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), not `localCompare`:

```
var disable = aDateUnit.localeCompare("weekly");
// add an 'e' ---------------^
```

(Did you not get an error in the console, something like `TypeError: Object weekly has no method 'localCompare'`?)

Comment: well, I'm new to JS programming, checking out the error console from now on.

Comment: Cool. Of course, sometimes there is no error in the console because the problem is some kind of logic error rather than a syntax or runtime error, but still the console is a good place to start.